# Node.js Express Automatic Routing

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a Node.js application that has many .html files. Rather than having to go and specify a routing for each and every one of them, **is there a way for the routing to be done automatically**?

Ideally this would happen:

Request received for "/Test.html". It then checks a given folder for a file called "Test.html". I can optionally override this automatic wiring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend using [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/guide.html) and it's static middleware:

```
app.configure(function(){
  ...
  var oneYear = 31557600000;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
});
```

If a request to /test.html is made, then the static middleware looks into the "public" folder and checks if the file exists (if it exists it serves it).

Comment: It might be worth cleaning up your answer to include just the magic line that makes it work. E.g.  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));